# Best practice of SearchClient usage

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sdk-.net

I am going to migrate our service to use Azure.Search.Documents (v11) SDK instead of raw HttpClient GET/POST to query documents from an azure search.

Per the SDK document, we need to initialize a SearchClient with a service endpoint and an index name. As our service is a multi-tenancy service which share multiple customers' indexes in the same search service (could be 3000 indexes on S3 HD service), so in theory, we need up to 3000 search client instances.

My question is, is it worth implementing a search client pool to reuse the client for the same index for better performance? Or can I just create a new search client each time when sending a request to azure search? Not sure if the SDK handles the client pool internally.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [best practices guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/) for working with client objects in Azure SDK. Reusing client instances (wherever possible) will result in better performing applications.